# PCRE2 not found in Mac

Tags: macos, pcre2

I have installed pcre2 version 10.37 by downloading the tar file and doing

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

When I run

> pcre2 --version

or

> which pcre2

In the terminal, I get command not found.

I am building my project that needs "pcre2" to compile successfully but after running "make" in the project directory I get the following:

```
   ERROR!  pcre2 library not found, go get it
   from www.pcre.org. Or from packages:
   Debian/Ubuntu: apt install libpcre2-dev
   Fedora: dnf install pcre2-devel
   CentOS/RHEL: yum install pcre2-devel

make: *** [config.status] Error 1
```

I can find the following files in /usr/local/lib/

[image]

Comment: I am running a project for which this library is needed. I get this error "PCRE2 not found" when I run make on my project. but as per the screenshot its there. I have added the path in bash file as well.

Comment: I am editing my description.
Yes I did. But still not able to compile in the project.